# How to use justify in chinese with colon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I tried

```
.td_justify{
text-align-last: justify;
}
```

And it shows

[image]

But what i want is Like

[image]

If i add `<td>` to fix it 
Then `colspan` will get something wrong

How can i fix it quickly?

sorry i said unClearly and i reupload img
 
img2 i just add space to finish it

Answer (score 0):

```
.td_justify:before{
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    content: '\FF1A';
}
```

Comment: sorry i said unclearly, Ur answer is worked but not what i want

Answer (score -1):

You can set it fixedly by  and padding.

Comment: While this post snippet may or may not solve the question, including an explanation along with some code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future